# Programmatic (Python) format check in jsonschema

Tags: python, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

I have a schema where a property should comply to a pattern that only can be checked programmatically:

```yaml
type: object
properties:
  unit:
    description: Unit of this column. Must be FITS conform.
    type: string
```

where "FITS conformity" can be ensured by a small Python snippet (which raises an exception on fail):

```
import astropy.units as u
u.Unit(col["unit"], format=u.format.Fits)
```

It seems that this could be done with a custom "format" attribute of the property:

```yaml
type: object
properties:
  unit:
    description: Unit of this column. Must be FITS conform.
    type: string
    format: fitsunit
```

and then implement a format checker with the decorator [jsonschema.FormatChecker.checks](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validate/#jsonschema.FormatChecker.checks). However, I could not find out how to write this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found this out myself. The decorator is used for a simple checker function, that takes one single argument:

```
from jsonschema import validate, Draft202012Validator

@Draft202012Validator.FORMAT_CHECKER.checks("fitsunit", ValueError)
def check_fitsunit(s):
    import astropy.units as u
    u.Unit(s, format=u.format.Fits)
    return True

validate(my_file, my_schema, format_checker=Draft202012Validator.FORMAT_CHECKER)
```